# Development server with Heroku?

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I'm building a Node.js application and I'm using Heroku as my host. I want to be able to maybe have a development subdomain for my app where I can test changes before I push it into production. It'd be great if I could do something like `git push heroku dev`, and access my prerelease code at `dev.myapp.heroku.com` or something similar. Is something like that possible without having to set up an entirely separate app? If not, how would I configure the toolbelt to push to 2 different Heroku apps from different branches of the same repository?

Answer (score 0):

I usually just create another app for staging
then add the remote for the new app like

`git remote add staging https://git.heroku.com/staging.git`

then you can push your development branch to the staging master branch like

`git push staging development:master`

i think it's actually kind of nice to have 2 different apps, so you can try out new settings or addons without messing with your production instance.

you can always add a dev.yourapp.com as a domain for this app, then point your dns to it. here is a link to a detailed way to do that
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Very easy. Use [Heroku Pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines).
You put your Dev app and your Production app in a pipeline (you might want to also add a Staging app in the pipeline - up to you).
The you push to your dev app from your development environment.
Test everything in the dev app, and when you're satisfied, you simply "Promote" the compiled slug to the next phase in the pipeline.